# ECHO Command with variable

Tags: batch-file, echo

I'm new to batch and I'm trying to make a speed/distance/time calculator. The code works fine until I try to echo the total. Here's my code:

```
@ECHO off
COLOR 0f
TITLE Speed Distance Time Calculator

:BEGIN
SET /P type="Calculate speed/distance/time? (S/D/T): "
CLS

IF /I "%type%"=="s" (
    SET /P distance="Distance: "
    CLS
    SET /P dUnits="Distance units (mile/m/km):"
    CLS
    SET /P time="Time: "
    CLS
    SET /P tUnits="Time units (h/s):"
    CLS
    SET total=%distance%/%time%
    ECHO %total%
)
```

It outputs:

```
ECHO is off
```

I've looked around for answers and have tried "enabledelayedexpansion" but it did not work.

Comment: Hey, a friendly comment, you dont have to worry about capitalizing commands in batch, nor things like `equ` or parameters like `/p`. Unless you prefer that, in which case do what you do.

Comment: Continuing the friendly comment, I used to write all commands and command parts in lowercase letters, and all options in uppercase (to easily distinguish they). I also use "camelCase" for variableName's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do division (or any arithmetic operation) in a batch file using the `SET` command, you have to specify the `/A` switch. Additionally, you'll need to turn on delayed variable expansion, since you will be dynamically changing variables in the batch file, and then using them.

When using delayed expansion variables you must reference them with `!` instead of `%`. The exclamation marks tell the command processor that you want that particular variable's expansion to be delayed. Any variables that use percentage signs will be expanded at initial parse time.

So at the top of your batch file, under the `@ECHO off`, turn on delayed expansion:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Then perform the calculation like so:

```
SET /A total=!distance!/!time!
ECHO !total!
```

Comment: check your variables. One of them is probably empty or contains invalid characters. Run your script with `@echo ON` to see any errormessages (and the commands, as they are actually executed)

Comment: Sorry I forgot that you will have to turn on delayed expansion. It worked for me because I ran it once, which set all the variables in my current environment, so when I ran it the second time with my changes all the variables already existed! I updated my answer.